# JetBrains Rider does not recognize the constructor generated by the attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jetbrains-ide

`[AutoConstructor]` in the code below will automatically generate a constructor (as shown in the figure below):
[image]

It works fine in Visual Studio, but JetBrains Rider has an error message:
[image]

I do not understand. . .

*(Because I am not good at English, I am using Google Translate to ask questions, please forgive me)*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using ComputeSharp;

namespace ComputeSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Allocate a writeable buffer on the GPU, with the contents of the array
            // Get some sample data
            int[] array = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).ToArray();

            // Allocate a GPU buffer and copy the data to it.
            // We want the shader to modify the items in-place, so we
            // can allocate a single read-write buffer to work on.
            using ReadWriteBuffer<int> buffer = Gpu.Default.AllocateReadWriteBuffer(array);
            
            // Launch the shader
            Gpu.Default.For(buffer.Length, new MultiplyByTwo(buffer));

            // Get the data back
            buffer.CopyTo(array);
        }
    }

    [AutoConstructor]
    public readonly partial struct MultiplyByTwo : IComputeShader
    {
        public readonly ReadWriteBuffer<int> buffer;

        public void Execute()
        {
            buffer[ThreadIds.X] *= 2;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://github.com/Sergio0694/ComputeSharp/issues/116 (and also https://github.com/Sergio0694/ComputeSharp#requirements):

> In order to work correctly, ComputeSharp also needs the source
> generator to be added to consuming projects as an analyzer, so that it
> can run when the code is being compiled.
>
> You can do so by adding the following code to your .csproj file, just
> like in the sample projects:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\ComputeSharp\ComputeSharp.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\ComputeSharp.SourceGenerators\ComputeSharp.SourceGenerators.csproj"
                      OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                      ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"
                      PrivateAssets="contentfiles;build" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Additionally, you need to ensure you are using .NET 5 (not an early version of .NET Framework / Core).

*If your issue persists, you may also wish to try using VS 2019 rather than Rider.*

Comment: This is indeed the problem. thank you very much!

Comment: @WMD2077 welcome to Stack Overflow. It's usual to accept an answer if it is correct and helpful, like this one appears to be for you.

Comment: Hi, @ WMD2077. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.